# Convert row names into new columns in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked elsewhere, but I've tried different attempts and nothing has worked so far.

In my data frame `Mesure` I would like to split the values of the column  `Row.names` into two new columns named `Sample_type` and `Locality`. I try to use a `tidyverse` solution but R returns me that the column must not be dupicated... How can I modify it ? Also, is it possible to remove the "<" ?

```
> head(Mesure)
            Row.names                mean_Mesure max_Mesure min_Mesure 
1 Aquatic_moss.Paris.AG-110m.<          100         110        90                      
2     Aquatic_moss.Paris.BE-7.          123         177        53                         
3   Aquatic_moss.Paris.CO-57.<          40          60         20            
4   Aquatic_moss.Paris.CO-58.<          40          50         30  
5   Aquatic_moss.Paris.CO-60.<          50          70         30         
6  Aquatic_moss.Paris.CS-134.<          200         300        100      
> 

> library(tidyverse)
> new_df <- Mesure %>% 
+   rownames_to_column(var = "Row.names") %>% 
+   separate(Row.names,sep = ".",into = c("Sample_type","Locality")) 

Error: Column name `Row.names` must not be duplicated.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: When you create `Mesure`, wouldn't  `as_tibble(..., rownames="Row.names")` give you what you want?

Comment: Well `Mesure` is the merging of several lists that come from the splitting of several different data frames. During splitting of these initial data frames, I renamed the dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To separate that with the first "dot" you can use:

```
Mesure %>%
    separate(Row.names, sep = "\\.", into = c("Sample_type", "Locality"), extra = "merge")
```

Explanation:

- You don't need to convert `rownames_to_column()`, because "Row.names" is already a column.
- `sep = "."` is not enough as the `.` is taken as a regular expression.
- There are many `.` in the column, so you need to specify `extra = "merge"` to separate only at first appearance. If you would like to keep only `"Paris"` without `AG-110m` etc, you specify `extra = "drop"` there.

Result with `extra = "merge"`:

```
   Sample_type        Locality mean_Mesure max_Mesure min_Mesure
1 Aquatic_moss Paris.AG-110m.<         100        110         90
2 Aquatic_moss     Paris.BE-7.         123        177         53
3 Aquatic_moss   Paris.CO-57.<          40         60         20
4 Aquatic_moss   Paris.CO-58.<          40         50         30
5 Aquatic_moss   Paris.CO-60.<          50         70         30
6 Aquatic_moss  Paris.CS-134.<         200        300        100
```

Result with `extra = "drop"`:

```
   Sample_type Locality mean_Mesure max_Mesure min_Mesure
1 Aquatic_moss    Paris         100        110         90
2 Aquatic_moss    Paris         123        177         53
3 Aquatic_moss    Paris          40         60         20
4 Aquatic_moss    Paris          40         50         30
5 Aquatic_moss    Paris          50         70         30
6 Aquatic_moss    Paris         200        300        100
```

If you need to drop `"<"` at the end of Locality column, run something like:

```
Mesure$Locality <- gsub("<$", "", Mesure$Locality)
```

where `"<$"` means "`<` at the end of the string".

Comment: To drop `"<"` in the same command line, it is also possible to use `extra = "drop"` : new_df <- Mesure %>% 
  separate(Row.names,sep = "\\.",into = c("Sample_type","Locality", "Chemicals"), extra = "drop")

Comment: @Sylvain Oh yes, this is even better! I was only thinking about two columns as you specified in the question, however separating the chemicals and dropping the rest is definitely a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies.  I should read your question properly.  The second part of your answer would be:

```
d %>% separate(Row.names, into=c("Sample_type","Locality"), extra="drop")
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Sample_type Locality mean_Mesure max_Mesure min_Mesure
  <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Aquatic     moss             100        110         90
2 Aquatic     moss             123        177         53
3 Aquatic     moss              40         60         20
4 Aquatic     moss              40         50         30
5 Aquatic     moss              50         70         30
6 Aquatic     moss             200        300        100
```

I can't help you with the first part because I don't know how you create the input data frame.